# Probability of a certain outcome

Tags: combinatorics

A bag of 14 marbles, 8 red and 6 blue and four marbles are to be chosen at random.

a) What is the probability that exactly 2 red marbles and 2 blue marbles are selected?

b) What is the probability that at least one blue marble is selected?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

(a)
$$P_a=\frac{\binom{6}{2} \binom{8}{2}}{\binom{14}{4}}=\frac{60}{143}$$

(b)
$$P_b=\frac{\binom{6}{4} \binom{8}{0}+\binom{6}{3} \binom{8}{1}+\binom{6}{2} \binom{8}{2}+\binom{6}{1} \binom{8}{3}}{\binom{14}{4}}=\frac{133}{143}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint on b):

What is the probability that no blue marbles are selected?